# How to Include a Security Token to the SOAP Request?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

here i want to add the security tocken to a SOAP request Message using c#, but I am unable to figure it out.Can any one help? 
here I have tried something like

```
Request.ServicesExternalClient se = new Request.ServicesExternalClient();
            se.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
            se.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password1";
            BindingElementCollection elements =  se.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();   
 elements.Add(SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement());
```

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.securitybindingelement.createusernameovertransportbindingelement(v=vs.110).aspx) is the description of CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement().

Answer (score 1):

A detailed example has been mentioned here:

[Add Security Credentials to a SOAP Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819938.aspx)